# Managing NodeJS + T.S/Flutter project with Gradle

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, gradle

I'm planning on creating a project that will involve two separate Typescript subprojects (a Node.js server and browser extension). I have found a [plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) for node and [typescript](https://github.com/sothmann/typescript-gradle-plugin). I also plan on having another subproject for a flutter app.

Are there any flutter gradle plugins available so I can integrate it as a subproject? I have found the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) to integrate flutter into an android application with gradle but don't really see it fitting into my niche here; unless I'm missing something from the page.

So my question is whether this project structure makes sense and if so what would be the best way to integrate flutter into it?

Comment: That specific plugin is dead, there's an actively maintained fork at https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin

Comment: @deepy I noticed! So I switched over. Thanks.